# Error with scala-2.8 and scalacheck: Prop has wrong version

Tags: scala, scalacheck

```
scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll                                      
error: error while loading Prop, Scala signature Prop has wrong version
 expected: 5.0
 found: 4.1 in /opt/scala-2.8/lib/scalacheck.jar(org/scalacheck/Prop.class)
```

It's the the actual scala-2.8, and scalacheck was updated with sbaz immediately before (sbaz update; sbaz upgrade).

Is scalacheck for scala-2.8 under development, and not suitable for 2.8, or what might be the problem?

Do I have to get the sources, and recompile scalacheck by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it from the [project page](http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/downloads/list). It seems that it is not updated to 1.7 in sbaz yet.

Answer (score 1):

ScalaCheck 1.7 for Scala 2.8 should be available in sbaz now.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't test it, because I already updated by hand.